# Unable to parse the format string in RealmSwift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

**Model**

```
class News: Object {
dynamic var ExternalId: String?
dynamic var Title: String?
dynamic var Preview: String?
dynamic var Description: String?
dynamic var PublicationDate: Date?
dynamic var ExternalUrl: String?
dynamic var ImageUrl: String?
dynamic var ViewTypeName: String?
dynamic var Status: Bool = true
dynamic var Like: Bool = false
dynamic var AuthorizedOnly: Bool = false

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "ExternalId"
}
```

**Use code:**

```
self.news = try! Realm().objects(News.self).filter("Like == YES").sorted(byProperty: "PublicationDate", ascending: true)
```

**Error:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "Like == YES"'

I try:

```
Like = YES
Like = true
Like = 1
```

But it's not work!

please help!

Comment: Try this "Like == true". And no you haven't tried that already.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like `NSPredicate` treats `Like` as a keyword not the property name. As a workaround you can use something like that:

```
.filter(NSPredicate(format: "%K == true", "Like"))
```